# BufferedWriter.write() does not seem to work

Tags: java, android, sockets, bufferedwriter

I have two Java applications, where an Android client connects to a server on a computer and sends a message using BufferedWriter over websockets.

The client:

```
    try {
        toast("Sending...");
        Socket sock = new Socket(ip, PORT);
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
        bw.flush();
        bw.write("Hello Server!");
        toast("Connected!");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        toast(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        toast(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket server;
    ConnectionThread ct;
    Socket s;
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting server...");
        server = new ServerSocket(1337);
        s = server.accept();
        ct = new ConnectionThread(s);
        es.execute(ct);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

The `ConnectionThread` class:

```
public class ConnectionThread implements Runnable {
    private Socket sock;
    private InputStream is;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private boolean online;
    public ConnectionThread(Socket s) {
        System.out.println("Creating connection thread.");
        this.sock = s;
        online = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String input = "";
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting to read...");
            is = sock.getInputStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while (online) {
                input = br.readLine();
                if(input != null){
                    System.out.print("Received message: ");
                    System.out.println(input);
                }

            }

            br.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the server, and then the client, the client will show the "Connected!" toast, and the server's output will be:

```
Starting server...
Creating connection thread.
Starting to read...
```

So, it seems like the connection is actually being made, but the message does not arrive. Does anybody know why this could be happening?

Comment: try to flush after you write, not before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server is expecting a complete line terminated by a newline. Try:

```
bw.write("Hello Server!");
bw.newLine();
```

Comment: Oh my... That's it indeed. I knew it was going to be something tiny yet obvious that I had overlooked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this...

```
String s = new String();

while ((br.readLine())!=null) {

                s = s+br.readLine();

                    System.out.print("Received message: ");
                    System.out.println(input);
                }

            }
```

**And**

```
     bw.println("Hello Server");
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you don't send an endline on your client, so the BufferedReader.readline() will never return, because it cannot match the \n-character. Try it again with

```
        bw.write("Hello Server!\n");
```

on the client side.